# how to check a column with multiple conditions in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check a column for multiple conditions.. 
the columns are

```
user_id    auction_id    status
  7            102         L
  7            103         W
  7            104         B
  7            105        null
```

now i want to select a auction_id based on userid and status so this is the initial code that i wrote

```
select auction_id 
from user_auction_rel 
where user_id =7 
  and status = 'B' 
   OR STATUS = NULL ;
```

the result was i got the auctionid 104 as status B was given first.
after checking out on the net, i came up with this code

```
select auction_id 
from user_auction_rel 
where status in ('L' , 'W') 
group by user_id = 7;
```

but this also returned a similar result.. only auction id with status L was returned.. so i need an sql query that will be able to return auction id based on both the statuses.. thanks in advance..

Comment: BWS, Michael Berkowski, Dan Bracuk, jvicab, 
Aman Aggarwal thanks to all of you for answering my query promptly..

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues with your first attempt.  First, you cannot compare `NULL` with the equality operator. You must use `STATUS IS NULL` instead.

Second, operator precedence is causing issues here. You need to enclose the `status = 'B' OR STATUS IS NULL` in a `()` group. Otherwise, the `AND` binds more tightly than the `OR` and you'll get incorrect results.

```
SELECT
  auction_id
FROM user_auction_rel
WHERE
  user_id =7
  AND (status = 'B' OR status IS NULL)
  /* or using the IN(): */
  /* AND (status = IN('L','W') OR status IS NULL) */
```

Here's a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb36e0/1

Your second attempt goes awry because of the `GROUP BY`.  Since you have no aggregates in the query (`MAX(),MIN(),COUNT(),SUM()`) there is no reason to use `GROUP BY`. The expression `group by user_id = 7` actually evaluates as `GROUP BY 1` and all results get grouped together. Where that would be an error in most other RDBMS, MySQL allows it and gives you an indeterminate result set back for the `auction_id` column.

Comment: thank you for answering my query promptly Michael Berkowski, and thank you for explaining it  so well .. :)

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses are your friends.  Your first query was this:

```
select auction_id 
from user_auction_rel  
where user_id =7  
and status = 'B' 
OR STATUS = NULL
```

But adding brackets changes the meaning altogether

```
select auction_id 
from user_auction_rel  
where user_id =7  
and 
(
status = 'B' 
OR STATUS is NULL 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The query should be:

select auction_id from user_auction_rel where user_id =7 and status = 'B' OR STATUS **IS** NULL ;

From this you will get both rows having status is null and status = B

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT auction_id FROM user_auction_rel WHERE user_id =7 AND (status = 'B' OR status IS NULL);
```

You need to enclose OR parts in parenthesis due to AND takes precedence. Also to check for null value, use IS NULL instead of = NULL